# Finding roots of a cubic equation

Tags: cubics

**Question:**

> If $6(8a + c) = 16b+ 3d$ then $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ has at least one root in:
>
> 1. $(-3,0)$
> 2. $(-4,0)$
> 3. $(-4,-3)$
> 4. $(0,2)$

**Attempt:**
Having solved several such questions, there is usually a hint hidden somewhere within the question. However, I can't find any hint anywhere in this question. I don't see any application of Rolle's theorem. I know for a fact that I could use the property that if $f(x)$ has a root in $(a,b)$ then $f(a)f(b) < 0$, but don't see any way of doing so unless I substitute every option into it. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: @Casteels Aha..... I posted the question while looking at my solution, which involved an attempt at differentiation, and thus the quadratic equation. Just a moment...... And yeah thanks for that. Stupid of me.

Comment: It seems unclear to me what you mean with these roots, I assume you are trying to find the values of $x$ where $f(x)=0$. Why are there 2 numbers in that case? Your function is defined as $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ right?

Comment: @Jan Those are the ranges in which the roots may be present. Basically, it means that the value of $x$ such that $f(X) = 0$ may be in between the two numbers given.

Comment: Of course, it is really obvious, I assumed they were points and not intervals, my mistake.

Comment: From the first equation we see $c=-8a$ and $d=\frac{-16}{3} c$. Substituting this into $f$ gives us: $$f(x)=ax(x^2-8a) + b(x^2-16/3)$$ This should help you a bit.

Comment: @Jan Slight typo in the question. No equality with zero. All fixed now. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given $48a-16b+6c-3d=0 \tag{1}$.

Rolle's theorem states that if a real-values function has equal values at two points then it must have a local extrema between them. So we need to find the anti-derivative $F(x)$ of $f(x)$ in order to apply:

$F(x) = \frac{1}{4}ax^4 + \frac{1}{3}bx^3 + \frac{1}{2}cx^2 + dx + k \tag{2}$

Then

$F(0) = k$.

Also,

$F(-4) = 64a - \frac{64}{3}b + 8c - 4d + k = \dfrac{4}{3}(48a-16b+6c-3d) + k = 0 = k = k$ by (1).

Hence $F(0) = F(-4)$ so $F(x)$ has a local extrema in $(-4,0)$ and so $f(x)$ has a root in $(-4,0)$.